# Plotting cumulative Income Distribution

Tags: plotting, distributions

I need some help in creating a plot that shows the Income Distribution of an economy.

The simple idea is to show the population percentage at the x-coordinate and the income percentage at the y-coordinate.

For example: I have a `list={0.2,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.1}` of the income percentage of 5 households (each household = 20% of population).

Now I would like to show in a plot that 20% (or 1 household) holds 30% of the whole income. 40% (or 2 households) hold 60% of the income. 60% (or 3 households) hold 80% of the whole income and so on.

Please could someone assist and help?

Comment: Have you seen `ListPlot`?

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1};

ListLinePlot[Accumulate[Prepend[Reverse@Sort@list, 0]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, DataRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> Axis,
 FrameTicks -> {{{.3, .6, .8, .9}, Automatic}, {Range[0, 1, .2], 
    Automatic}},
 Mesh -> {Range[0, 1, .2]}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 1, .2], {.3, .6, .8, .9}}] (*thanks: Bob Hanlon*)
```

[image]

To get the standard [Lorenz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve):

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, Accumulate[Sort@Prepend[list, 0]]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, DataRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that you want `Accumulate[Prepend[Reverse@Sort@list, 0]]`

Comment: yes, thank you @BobHanlon.

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon and @kglr! That is a big help!